# cURL through CLI fails sometimes

Tags: curl, https, cron, console, command-line-interface

I need to run an app through a web server from a cron job

This is the command I'm trying to use:

```
curl -k domainname:8888/url/path
```

This web runs with https, using an insecure SSL certificate of our own. The first time I run it from console, it always displays:

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Occasionally it happens again when I immediately try again, but in general, the second time I try, the script within this app is executed.

What should I do to avoid the described error on any execution?

**EDIT:**

If I add the --verbose option, this is what I get on execution:

```
* About to connect() to domainname port 8888
*   Trying 12.345.67.89... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0

curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Comment: Lots of different things can cause a connection error. It could be your computer, some piece of equipment between you and the server, or the server itself. I suggest you enable verbose output, `curl --verbose -k domain:8888/url/path/`. That will give you additional information, which might help you diagnose the error.

Comment: @JimMischel I've added more info related to the --verbose option you suggested.

Comment: "Connection refused" means that the server you tried to contact refused your connection request. There is nothing wrong with cURL or CLI or your system. You need to find out why the server refused. Are making a lot of concurrent requests, or many requests in a short period? Look up connection refused for other causes, or ask the administrators of the server.

Comment: @Jimmischel I'll do. Thanks for the info!